# Rectangles and squares of trominoes filling a grid

Tags: mathematics, geometry, tiling, polyomino

Let's have a board 24 squares by 24 squares. This board is to be filled with trominoes of three different colors. There are equal numbers of trominoes of each color. The board is to be filled with three 8x12 rectangles, six 4x6 rectangles, and four 6x6 squares. Two trominoes of the same color are not allowed to touch side by side anywhere and trominoes are not allowed to form pairs. A tromino is a geometric figure as shown in a Figure A, and a pair is shown in Figure B.

[image: L-tromino shown as "Figure A". Two L-trominoes which together form a 2 by 3 rectangle shown as "Figure B".]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, without rotating any rectangles:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with rotations and substitutions:

> [image]